# Right Mouse Button in FileOpenDialog window gives an error

Tags: c++, openfiledialog, hwnd, hresult

I have a FileOpenDialog that gets a selected folder name, this works perfectly however when I click an item in a folder or another folder with the right mouse button the application crashes and throws an Unhandled Exception:Module Not Found. I'd like to be able to use the right mouse button so I wouldn't want to block it. I'm looking for a solution to handle the input from the Right Mouse Button so the application doesn't crash.

```
HWND Hwnd;
std::vector<std::string> openFileDialog(std::vector<COMDLG_FILTERSPEC> filterSpec, bool allowMultiSelect)
{
std::vector<std::string> paths;

IFileOpenDialog *pFileOpen;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IFileOpenDialog, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFileOpen));
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    if (allowMultiSelect)
    {
        pFileOpen->SetOptions(FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT);
    }
    pFileOpen->SetFileTypes(filterSpec.size(), filterSpec.data());

    hr = pFileOpen->Show(Hwnd);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IShellItemArray* results;
        hr = pFileOpen->GetResults(&results);

        pFileOpen->GetResults(&results);
        DWORD itemCount = 0;
        DWORD iterator = 0;
        results->GetCount(&itemCount);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            for (iterator = 0; iterator < itemCount; iterator++)
            {
                PWSTR pszFilePath;
                IShellItem *pItem;
                results->GetItemAt(iterator, &pItem);
                hr = pItem->GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, &pszFilePath);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    LPWSTR path = pszFilePath;
                    std::wstring file = path;
                    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> convert;
                    paths.push_back(convert.to_bytes(file));

                }
                pItem->Release();
            }
        }
    }
}

pFileOpen->Release();
if (paths.size() == 0)
    paths.push_back("FAILED");

return paths;
```

}

Comment: You don't get to just debug your own code when you use FileOpenDialog, you also get all of the shell extensions that you have installed on your machine loaded into your process.  Programmers tend to have a lot of them and quality is, well, not exactly guaranteed.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to eliminate the evildoer.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that another process or installed program on my computer will sort of "corrupt" the usage of FileOpenDialog and therefore make it crash? I tested the software on multiple computers though and it consistently crashes when using RMB on any object that is in a folder. Wouldn't that mean that it's not my specific pc that has trouble? and if not, any idea what kind of processes I should look for? Thanks so much

Comment: RMB is a TLA that IDK.  Post the stack trace if you want better guesses.

Comment: RMB = Right Mouse Button

Comment: I've looked into it and it seems that I found the evildoer, Thanks so much